# bash - dialog command - "select all" button

Tags: bash, dialog, ubuntu-20.04

The link below:
https://serverfault.com/questions/144939
It correctly shows how to create a menu using the "dialog" command but does not show how to create the "select all" shortcut button.
How to create the "Select all" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

onoff=off # all unset by defaul
dialog1(){ dialog --output-fd 1 --extra-button --extra-label "Select All" --checklist "Select options:" 0 0 0 "$@"; }
dialog2(){ choices=$(dialog1 "${options[@]}"); }

set_options(){ # make options array dynamic
    options=(
        1 "Option 1" $onoff
        2 "Option 2" $onoff
        3 "Option 3" $onoff
        4 "Option 4" $onoff
    )
}

set_option
dialog2

case $? in          # if 'Select All' presssed
     3) onoff=on    # set all to on
        set_options # reassemble options
        dialog2;;   # and run dialog again
esac

clear
echo $choices
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, thank you.
Taking a cue from your solution, merging it with that of the link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/144939
and improving the code in my own way, I got this solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
onoff=off
cmd=(dialog --output-fd 1 --separate-output --extra-button --extra-label "Select All" --cancel-label "Select None" --checklist "Select options:" 0 0 0)
load-dialog () {
    options=(
                1 "Option 1" $onoff
                2 "Option 2" $onoff
                3 "Option 3" $onoff
                4 "Option 4" $onoff
    )
    choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}")
}
load-dialog
exit_code="$?"
while [[ $exit_code -ne 0 ]]; do
case $exit_code in
    1) clear; onoff=off; load-dialog;;
    3) clear; onoff=on; load-dialog;;
esac
exit_code="$?"
done
clear
for choice in $choices
do
    case $choice in
        1) echo "First Option";;
        2) echo "Second Option";;
        3) echo "Third Option";;
        4) echo "Fourth Option";;
    esac
done
sleep infinity
```